# Can I create a Private API Gateway and deploy without creating a resource policy in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I want to deploy a Private API Gateway without a resource policy attached to it.

In AWS console, I first created a Private API Gateway and Attached a resource policy as follows

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "execute-api:/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I deployed and it worked, now I want to deploy again without the resource policy but the console is not allowing me to deploy without a resource policy, it is throwing this error

`Private REST API doesn't have a resource policy attached to it`

As the second point mentioned in [Create and attach an API Gateway resource policy to an API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-create-attach.html)

Quote `For private APIs, note that until you attach the resource policy to the private API, all calls to the API will fail`

it does not specifically mention that it is mandatory to attach a resource policy when we are deploying the API Gateway. It just mentions that the endpoint will fail, in such case shouldn't we be able to deploy without a resource policy.

How can I deploy without resource policy.